# Blazor EditContext : How to check validation message for nested object

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have an extension method to check if a specific field is valid or not.

```
        public static bool IsValid(this EditContext editContext, string fieldName)
        {
            var fieldIdentifier = editContext.Field(fieldName);

            editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);

            var result = !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();

            Console.WriteLine($"{fieldName}  : {result}");

            return result;
        }
```

It's working fine for non-complex fields but not for complex fields. e.g

My model is

```
    public class RegisterCompanyRequest
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Maximum allowed length for company name is 200 characters")]
        public string NameEn { get; set; }

        [ValidateComplexType]
        public List<CompanyLocation> CompanyLocations { get; set; }

        [ValidateComplexType]
        public CompanyAdminInfo CompanyAdminInfo { get; set; } = new CompanyAdminInfo();
    }

    public class CompanyAdminInfo
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Full name is required")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Maximum allowed length for full name is 200 characters")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyLocation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Maximum allowed length for location name is 200 characters")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and if I pass that method `NameEn` it returns false if validation fails and true otherwise, but if i pass it `CompanyLocations[0].Name` or `CompanyAdminInfo.FullName` it always return true.

How can I achieve the same functionality for nested objects in my Model?

**To Reproduce:** Copy the below code to new blazor WASM project.
also install the following package to validate complex type (Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation -Version 3.2.0-rc1.20223.4)

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<p>"Name" : @company.Name <span>@nameValid</span> </p> 
<p>"Admin Name" : @company.Admin.Name <span>@adminNameValid</span> </p>

<EditForm EditContext="editContext">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />

    <input type="text" @bind-value="@company.Name"/>

    <input type="text" @bind-value="@company.Admin.Name"/>

    <button @onclick="Validate" type="submit">Validate</button>
</EditForm>


@code
{
    private bool nameValid, adminNameValid;
    private Company company = new Company();

    EditContext editContext { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        editContext = new(company);
    }

    private async Task Validate()
    {
        var isValid = IsValid(editContext, "Name");

        nameValid = isValid;

        isValid = IsValid(editContext, "Admin.Name");

        adminNameValid = isValid;
    }

    public bool IsValid(EditContext editContext, string fieldName)
    {
        var fieldIdentifier = editContext.Field(fieldName);

        editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);

        return !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();
    }

    public class Company
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ValidateComplexType] /*(Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation -Version 3.2.0-rc1.20223.4)*/
        public Admin Admin { get; set; } = new Admin();
    }

    public class Admin
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a Minimal Reproducible Sample? ( [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) )

Comment: @daniherrera Thank you for your reply, I have added the code to reproduce the issue, Many thanks.

Comment: @daniherrera the other question you mentioned, for him ValidateComplexType is not working, It's working for me. so is there any way to get error messages for a nested object?

Comment: I posted an answer. Sorry about delay.

Comment: Hi Zubair, I came on this a "little" late (20 days), but been away.  Do you still want suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis thank you for your comment. I solve the problem and posted the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, do you have two antipatterns in your code.

First one is to call, by hand, `editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);`. Let Blazor deal with notifications.

The second one is with Submit, in my opinion, you should to avoid calling functions on `submit` button. Instead of that, use `OnValidSubmit` or `OnInvalidSubmit` at `EditForm` component level, or bind a function to `editContext.OnValidationStateChanged` like in my running sample bellow.

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@implements IDisposable

<EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmit">
    
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    
    <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="@company.Name" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => company.Name)" />

    <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="@company.Admin.Name" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => company.Admin.Name)" />
    
    <button type="submit">Validate</button>
    
</EditForm>

<p>"Name" : @company.Name <span>@nameValid</span> </p> 
<p>"Admin Name" : @company.Admin.Name <span>@adminNameValid</span> </p>

@code
{
    private bool? nameValid, adminNameValid;
    private Company company = new Company();

    EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new(company);
        editContext.OnValidationStateChanged += HandleValidationStateChanged;
    }

    private void HandleValidationStateChanged(object? o, ValidationStateChangedEventArgs args) 
    {
        var name_field = FieldIdentifier.Create( () => company.Name  );
        nameValid = IsValid(editContext, name_field);

        var admin_name_field = FieldIdentifier.Create( () => company.Admin.Name  );
        adminNameValid = IsValid(editContext, admin_name_field);

    }

    private void ValidSubmit()
    {
        nameValid = true;
        adminNameValid = true;
    }

    public bool IsValid(EditContext editContext, FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
        =>
        !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();

    public class Company
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Identifier too long (3 character limit).")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

        [ValidateComplexType] /*(Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation -Version 3.2.0-rc1.20223.4)*/
        public Admin Admin { get; set; } = new Admin();
    }

    public class Admin
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Identifier too long (3 character limit).")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (editContext is not null)
        {
            editContext.OnValidationStateChanged -= HandleValidationStateChanged;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually, the code I mentioned above is just to reproduce the issue. I am using OnValidSubmit, my actual scenario is that I have a form with many fields so I created different steps to complete each step with some fields, and have a Next button to move to the next step. so when the user clicks on the Next button I check if all fields in the current step are valid.

your example helped, Instead of passing the field name to edit context. Field, now as in your example I am creating FieldIdentifier using FieldIdentifier.Create(Expression<Func<T>>) and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes, move to `FieldIdentifier.Create(Expression<Func<T>>)` solves the problem to locate form field status. The others part of the answer are also important (like using `editForm` events to track field changes or validation changes).

Comment: actually, I want to check validation for groups of fields (Multiple groups on different conditions) without submitting or before moving away from that screen, so that's why i am doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Created an extension method.

```
    public static class EditContextHelper
    {
        public static bool IsValid(this EditContext editContext, Expression<Func<Object>> field)
        {
            var fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(field);

            editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);

            return !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();
        }
    }
```

using it like,

```
var field = model.CompanyLocations[0].Name
var result = EditContext.IsValid(field);
```

in my case i am using array to loop through specif fields like this.

```
var isValid = false;
var fieldsToValidate = new Expression<Func<Object>>[]
       {
           () => model.NameEn, () => (model.Address), () => model.Lattitude,
           () => model.Longitude , () => (model.Tel1), () => (model.Tel2), () => (model.Mobile), () => (model.Whatsapp),
           () => (model.Email), () => (model.Url), () => (model.TaxNumber) 
         };

foreach (var field in fieldsToValidate)
   {
       var result = EditContext.IsValid(field);

       if (!result)
       {
          isValid = false;
       }
    //doing something if any of the fields is wrong.
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks to @dani-herrera answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72439989/12845686)

Comment: In my opinion is better to use editForm events (OnValidationRequested,  OnValidationStateChanged, OnFieldChanged)

Comment: @daniherrera actually, I want to check validation for groups of fields (Multiple groups on different conditions) without submitting or before moving away from that screen, so that's why I am doing it manually.